# Creating multiple functions of the same type, Can anyone make this work?

Tags: python, variables, binary, boolean-logic, reportlab

Working on a longstanding project now, where I at least believe I have to utilise hundreds of different similar functions. I have asked this question at least four times in at least as many ways and have so far not received any viable information back.

This will be the last time I post about this, in case anyone is tired of seeing it, But what I have noticed most from my post is that people cant understand why I would possibly need "hundreds" of similar functions. So I will do my best to explain what I am aiming to accomplish.

I am writing a program that reads csv files for services. Currently there are '6 Services' in my program. Ideally, the program would make an Invoice for these services, and have them displayed as such:

```
Service 1
Service 2
Service 3
Service 4
Service 5
Service 6
```

However... In my program, before I came up with the solution I will show you next, The output if a service was blank or empty, would be as such:

```
Service 1
Service 2

Service 4

Service 6
```

Whereas, I would prefer the list to come out looking like this

```
Service 1
Service 2
Service 4
Service 6
```

Now, to accomplish this function using Python ReportLabs, A normal function would look like this:

```
def print1():
   c.setFont('Deja', 12, leading=None)
   c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC1, Service1)
   c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC2, Service2)
   c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC3, Service3)
   c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC4, Service4)
   c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC5, Service5)
   c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC6, Service6)
```

However, the print1() function would leave blank lines like the first example, if the variable containing the service is empty.
Thanks for reading all of that, and if you are still here and willing to help, I will get to the real problem now.

If we test whether a string/service is empty or full, and create a boolean to represent that string/service,then with the possibility of being empty or full, 3 services have 8 possible combinations of where the strings can be placed.

for example, if string 1 and 3 are empty, but string 2 is not, then the booleans we test would be 0&1&0. Now you can see that for 3 Services, There are 8 unique combinations

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

And judging by this fact, we can tell that 6 or 8 or 10 services, could lead to up to 1024 possible compinations of ten digit booleans, (i.e.0000000000-1111111111, 0 being empty, 1 being full)

Now that I have explained the issue of there being so many possible combinations, depending on how many services you will need, my final question is this.

How would you guys go about doing something like this?
Currently my program handles 6 services, with 64 possible combinations written to 64 individual functions, which are iterated through by a dictionary, after the csv file has had all strings tested.

I will include my current solution here, and I would like to add that the only way I can see doing this right now is by writing a longer version of what I've done. but I really don't want to do that 1 or 2 thousand times lol. Anyways here is my solution >

```
#BitRep= 000000
def print1():
c.setFont('Deja', 12, leading=None)
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC1, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC2, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC3, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC4, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC5, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC6, " ")

#BitRep=000001
def print2():
c.setFont('Deja', 12, leading=None)
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC1, "Service 6")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC1, str(service6))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC1, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC1, str(singleTAXamountSVC6))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC1, str(fullTAXamountSVC6))
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC2, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC3, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC4, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC5, " ")
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC6, " ")

ETC.
ETC.

#BitRep=111111
def print64():
c.setFont('Deja', 12, leading=None)
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC1, "Service 1 ")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC1, str(service1))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC1, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC1, str(singleTAXamountSVC1))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC1, str(fullTAXamountSVC1))
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC2, "Service 2 ")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC2, str(service2))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC2, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC2, str(singleTAXamountSVC2))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC2, str(fullTAXamountSVC2))
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC3, "Service 3 ")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC3, str(service3))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC3, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC3, str(singleTAXamountSVC3))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC3, str(fullTAXamountSVC3))
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC4, "Service 4 ")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC4, str(service4))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC4, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC4, str(singleTAXamountSVC4))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC4, str(fullTAXamountSVC4))
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC5, "Service 5 ")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC5, str(service5))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC5, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC5, str(singleTAXamountSVC5))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC5, str(fullTAXamountSVC5))
c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC6, "Service 6 ")
c.drawString(250, YdrawLocationSVC6, str(service6))
c.drawString(330, YdrawLocationSVC6, "13 %")
c.drawString(400, YdrawLocationSVC6, str(singleTAXamountSVC6))
c.drawString(470, YdrawLocationSVC6, str(fullTAXamountSVC6))
```

I would love to see some of your guys solutions for this, as you can see, mine is definitely not the right way to be going about this.

I have also been entertaining the idea of a small script that will write all of these 1024 or however many functions out for me. I would like to share that as well in case anyone has any ideas on how to make it work.

these are just two functions in a script i wrote, One that makes the cases{} Dictionary, and one which makes all of the Funtions 
print1-print1024

```
def testMAKECASEDICTIONARYfromFIle():
# This function can be used to create a Case Dictionary in the format
```

# of CASE : Function. Function can be fed any lined text file.

```
print "cases = {"
# filepath = '/home/smiley/Desktop/sampletenbools'
filepath = '/home/smiley/Desktop/10boolsALL'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    num = 1
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
        var = line
        # print var
        print("{} : {}".format(str(line).strip("\n"), "Print"+ str(num))+",")
        num+=1
print "}"
```

The function Above creates cases 1-1024, bases on a text file i used a wordlist manipulator to generate.

The next and final function I will be adding, is responsible for writing the functions one by one, though It does not work perfectly yet. Again I would more than appreciate feedback/suggestions.

def testFIle():
    # This Function will be used to enumerate through the same file you used to create the switch dictionary,
    # but will define a function for each line.

```
# filepath = '/home/smiley/Desktop/sampletenbools'
filepath = '/home/smiley/Desktop/10boolsALL'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    num = 1
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
        var = line
        b1 = str(var)[0]
        b2 = str(var)[1]
        b3 = str(var)[2]
        b4 = str(var)[3]
        b5 = str(var)[4]
        b6 = str(var)[5]
        b7 = str(var)[6]
        b8 = str(var)[7]
        b9 = str(var)[8]
        b10 = str(var)[9]

        # YdrawLocationSVC1=490
        # YdrawLocationSVC2=475
        # YdrawLocationSVC3=460
        # YdrawLocationSVC4=445
        # YdrawLocationSVC5=430
        # YdrawLocationSVC6=415
        # YdrawLocationSVC7=400
        # YdrawLocationSVC8=375
        # YdrawLocationSVC9=360
        # YdrawLocationSVC10=345

        if b1 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC1=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC2=490
        if b1 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC1 = 490

        if b2 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC2=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC3=475
        if b2 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC2 = 475

        if b3 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC3=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC4=1111
        if b3 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC3 = 460

        if b4 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC4=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC5=1111
        if b4 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC4 = 445

        if b5 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC5=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC6=1111
        if b5 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC5 = 430

        if b6 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC6=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC7=1111
        if b6 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC6 = 415

        if b7 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC7=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC8=1111
        if b7 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC7 = 400

        if b8 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC8=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC9=1111
        if b8 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC8 = 385

        if b9 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC9=1111
            YdrawLocationSVC10=1111
        if b9 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC9 = 370

        if b10 == "0":
            YdrawLocationSVC10=1111
        if b10 == "1":
            YdrawLocationSVC10 = 355


        print "# Bitrep ="+str(var).strip("\n")
        print "def Print"+str(num)+"():"
        print"\tc.setFont('Deja', 12, leading=None)"
        print "\t# SERVICE NAME"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC1)+", stringn1)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC2)+", stringn2)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC3)+", stringn3)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC4)+", stringn4)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC5)+", stringn5)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC6)+", stringn6)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC7)+", stringn7)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC8)+", stringn8)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC9)+", stringn9)"+\
        "\n\tc.drawString(100, "+str(YdrawLocationSVC10)+", stringn10)"




        # print("{} : {}".format(str(line).strip("\n"), "Print" + str(num)))
        num += 1
        # print "\n"
```

Again, Thank you so much to anyone who actually read all of this, And even more so to anyone who has any input or advice that they'd like to share with me.

And to be more clear as requested below, I am aiming to remove the blank lines from the equation altogether. How I would like to do this is still up in the air, based on your thoughts.

User @bendl has requested I give this extra tad of info, For those 4 examples, 00 01 10 11, the boolean string would be crafted like this.

```
for n in line:
   var = n
   if str(var)==""
       bool1=0
       and draw string 2 at location 1
   if str(var)=!""
       bool1=1
       draw string 1 at location 1
```

However, the longer these boolean sets continue, the more advanced your if statement gets. I've tried making one of these for six services and it got way to complex, a dictionary was more managed.

Comment: Generally, one would use branching instead of creating 1000s of different functions. If you can provide the logic for creating the functions I can almost guarantee you can do this in only one function

Comment: @bendl !That sounds amazing, I am looking into branching right now, But do you think you would be able to give me an example for something small like 2 booleans? 11, 00, 10, and 01, are the only possible combinations for that, would you be able to show branching in a function like that?

Comment: You are making the question far too complex to get the help you need - and far too specific to your application. Think about the smallest question you can ask (maybe you need to combine several questions), then think about how you might ask it in a generic way -- presenting perhaps a hypothetical situation. I can't tell if you are asking how to not print the empty lines, how to get rid of if statements, what? If you had to condense your question to a single sentence.....?

Comment: Ah, @bendl , I see that branching is simply an if else type statement, and unfortunatly that would still take just as many if/elif statements.

Comment: Yes I am aiming to get rid of the blank lines, I apologise if that was not clear. @SteveJ

Comment: I'm fairly sure we could, but as SteveJ said, you're not quite giving the right information. While we appreciate the effort put into crafting a good question (many people don't), we need more information about the logic and less about the overall architecture. Tell us what those 4 examples should look like in your example and how you arrived at that solution, and we'll see if we can help. Also it may be that it requires the same number of if statements, but I actually quite doubt it.

Comment: @bendl I could definitely be wrong about the number of if statements. I will update m post at the bottom with the four examples you have requested.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is get rid of the blank lines, can you just conditionally make the call? "if Services2 is not None: c.drawString(100, YdrawLocationSVC2, Service2)"

Comment: just check if the service is a valid one before printing it

Comment: @SteveJ Because once Service two is no longer missing, every service below that needs to have its location reduced by one. Now say service 2 and 5 were missing, you would need to dictate service 1 to location 1, service 3 to location 2, service 4 to location 3, and service 6 to location 4. Rather than just being left with empty or overwritten strings

Answer (score 1):

I think you need such a print function: (I will comment in the code where needed)

```
def ultimateprint(bitlist, numberOfBools):
    if len(bitlist)!=numberOfBools: #check if bitlist is long enough
        break
    index = 1 #will count the n-th bit that is read
    index2 = 1 # will count the n-th service that was requested
    for bit in bitlist:
        if bit: #bit is 1, service n was requested
            printWithLineNeeded("Service " + str(index2), index) # I used this printWithLineNeeded to simplify
#the code you used to get the combined string where you need it.

            index2 +=1 #count up the number of services that were requested
        else: #bit is not one, empty line will be printed
            printEmptyLineInYourWay(index) #index gives which line is empty in your code
        index += 1 #end of iteration, one more bit was proceeded
```

bitlist must be something like `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`, **a list of ints**. The first 1 says that the first service was requested, the second isn't, the third is, and so on. This has the advantage that python interpretes them as ints or as bools, depending on how you formulate the code.

numberOfBools is actually not needed but gives you security that the length of the bitlist is that same as the number of Services that you have.

A for loop is dynamic and I wondered that in your previous questions nobody had that idea.

I really hope I could help you. Please feel free ta ask for clarifications if needed!

Comment: In his example, OP shows that the rest of the services are printed after the last `1` bit, in order. So perhaps pop them onto a queue instead of `printEmptyLineInYourWay` and then iterate through them at the end?

Comment: Yeah, thats possible too. In this case you would need to stack the actual requested services into a dictionary or a list, and print it then in a single print-task

Answer (score 1):

I very much agree with monamona's answer, but here's another, using a dictionary, as OP suggested.

```
# service1 = 'a'
# service2 = 'b'
# service3 = 'c'
# service4 = 'd'
# service5 = 'e'
# service6 = 'f'
# service7 = 'g'
# service8 = 'h'

serviceList = [service1, service2, service3, service4, service5, service6, service7, service8]
locationList = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8]
bitlist = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

serviceDict = {(not bit, enumeration[0]) : enumeration[1] for bit, enumeration in zip(bitlist, enumerate(serviceList))}
for key, location in zip(sorted(serviceDict.keys()), locationList):
    if not key[0]:
        print(serviceDict[key])
        print(location)
    else:
        print()
```

With this solution, simply replace the `print` statements with however you were originally printing solutions. Commented lines at the top are there if you want to run without the service methods defined.

This works because `False` can be interpreted as `0` and `True` as `1`, so we first flip the bit coming in with a `not` and then make a tuple with the resulting boolean and the service number, so that when it is sorted, it will sort first by the bit associated with the service and then the number of the service.

This all looks and sounds pretty complicated, and I definitely think monamona's solution is more readable, but it's really pretty simple if you step through it and should do the trick using a dictionary.

Comment: Hey All, MonaMona, Bendl, Everyone else, thank you all for your input, I passed out this morning, but cant wait to try out both of the solutions you have provided me, they both look very promising, and I will choose whichever works best for me as the correct answer. Thank you both very much for your time and effort :) You greatly make up for the rest of the community!

Comment: Hi Again guys, wanted to add, that Though those are both excellent solutions for creating the dictionarys/Booleansets, Unless I am misunderstanding them, They would still require me to write hundreds and hundreds of seperate functions would they not?

Comment: your solution seems to work very closely to what I need, however the location would have to shift from lower to higher on the page based on how many services before it are missing

Comment: @OwenRedo That's what `locationList` is for. Put the locations you want to print at in order in that list instead of `l1, l2, l3, ...` and it should work for you